# Trying to install composer on mac

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-mavericks, composer-php

I'm trying to reinstall a fresh copy of composer onto my mac and when I went to do so this is what happened when I ran the command in iTerm.

```
mine-imac:~ mine$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
-bash: curl: command not found
-bash: php: command not found
```

Can someone help me understand why this is happening because I can't find any other people that have come across this which seems odd.

EDIT:

I'm being told that one issue is that since CURL and PHP are not found and its supposed to come with my iMac apache. This has worked before but not sure what I did to have it not work. I am using Mamp Pro on my local computer if that helps.

Comment: It looks like your PATH is wrong. Try looking at your `~/.profile` to see if it has changed.

Comment: Where is the .profile fie located.

Comment: In your home directory. Type `cd; cat .profile`

Comment: mine-imac:~ mine$ cd; cat.profile
-bash: cat.profile: command not found

Comment: `cat     .profile` with a space

Comment: mine-imac:~ mine$ cat .profile -bash: cat: command not found

Comment: `/bin/cat   .profile`

Comment: no such file or directory.

Comment: It's probably called `.bash_profile`.  These are user-level questions, not developer-level.

Comment: Sorry I was able to get it back to working I created a .profile file and added in export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin:$PATH  however I'm trying to move the composer.phar file to my bin but I can't locate it on my system.